# Finding lost Ocelots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I didn't realize that upon quitting Minecraft, your Ocelots automatically sit. When I logged back in, I went off adventuring again, but I didn't notice that my Ocelots weren't following me. Now I can't find them at all!

How can you get Ocelots that are sitting down to teleport to you?

Comment: Quite simply, you can't, at least without mods. Perhaps you'd be better off asking for a mod or server plugin that would allow you to unsit them or at least identify their locations.

Comment: Since this only exists in a weekly build, I would just wait and see if it gets fixed, or alert @Notch via twitter.

Comment: ocelots? you mean cats, ocelots are the wild ones who run away from you.

Comment: @Resorath Well 1.2 just came out, so I'll see if a mod shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't find a lost ocelot unless you know the coordinates that you logged off. But in SMP servers there is a glitch that the ocelots and wolves dont sit when you log back on and if they are in a 1x1 space will act as if sitting.  So you could set up a temporary smp server to get them to teleport to you. But the server this happened on had towny, lockette, and other mods like those.